# CSS not shown in Django?

Tags: django

I have a tree structure like this:

```
.
|-- backend.py
|-- backend.pyc
|-- functions.py
|-- functions.pyc
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- models.py
|-- models.pyc
|-- templates
|   |-- css
|   |   |-- PIE.htc
|   |   `-- style.css
|   |-- form.html
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- index.html~
|   |-- reform.html
|   |-- style.css
|   |-- synced.html
|   |-- test.html
|   `-- thanks.html
|-- tests.py
|-- views.py
`-- views.pyc
```

I have given the path in STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/zurelsoft/workspace/genelaytics/fileupload/templates/css'
```

Whenever I open the template index.html it doesn't read the css. What am I doing wrong?

**Link** tag in template:

```
<title>.:: Genalytics ::.</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Show us your template file. Also please consider following the standard practices (putting static files separately from templates, in `static` directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your solution, namely you:

- keep static files with templates - it is not the same (templates are dynamically interpreted HTML document structures filled with data passed from views),
- use relative & fixed URLs in templates, instead of doing it dynamically and using absolute URLs,
- set static files root directory as `.../css`, but then refer to the names of the files using mentioned directory,
- you hardcode location of the static files (it is not a problem unless you move your app - there are better ways to do that),

Solution for you is simple: manage your static files as mentioned [in the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Quickfix is changing the HTML into this:

```
<title>.:: Genalytics ::.</title>
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

If it does not work, make sure you follow [mentioned documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) strictly. There can be several reasons why it may not work, namely:

- incorrect value of `STATIC_URL`,
- lack of proper context in the template,
- some other settings influencing the location of static files,
- the name of the static file itself,
- the location of the file vs. request path (like `STATIC_URL` being relative instead of absolute),